# What is the interior of the standard-$n$-simplex?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, elementary-set-theory

Taken from here [Boundary/interior of $0$-simplex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465338/boundary-interior-of-0-simplex)

The standard-$n$-simplex $\Delta^n$ is the subspace
$$
\textstyle
\Delta^n = 
\{x=(x_0,\dots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid \sum_0^n x_i=1,\,x_i\ge0\,\forall i \}
$$

Question what is the interior of the above simplex?

Originally, I thought it is simply:

$$
\textstyle
\text{int}\Delta^n = 
\{x=(x_0,\dots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid \sum_0^n x_i<1,\,x_i\ge0\,\forall i \}
$$

But then it seems stuff in the interior do add up to $1$.

So instead it should be:

$$
\textstyle
\text{int}\Delta^n = 
\{x=(x_0,\dots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^{n+1}\mid \sum_0^n x_i=1,\,x_i>0\,\forall i \}
$$

Which one is correct?

Comment: Note that this is true for the combinatorial interior of the simplex. It's topological interior is empty as long as the simplex's dimension does not match the space dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is correct. Let $n=2$. Your standard simplex is then $x+y+z=1, x,y,z \ge 0$. The boundary has at least one coordinate equal to zero, two in the corners. The interior then has all coordinates positive.